# window.open returning null after launching the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to restrict users from opening more than one IFrame window for my application. My code is as below,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test for Window Already Open</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script>

var gmyWin=null;

function myOpenWindow(winURL,winName,winFeatures,winObj)
{
  var theWin;
  theWin = window.open(winURL,winName,winFeatures);
  // here theWin variable is null
  return theWin;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Click this link to open the new window:</h1>
<p><a href='javascript:;' onClick='javascript:gmyWin=myOpenWindow("http://example:7001/tester/helloworld.jsp","myWin","height=630,width=1100",gmyWin);return false'>open new window</a> </p>
</body>
```

I try accessing theWin variable but it always return null. I want to check if the window is open or not but I am not able to check, window.open is returning null after opening the URL.
Please help me how to correct the issue.

Comment: why don't you use window.location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a flag.

```
function myOpenWindow(winURL,winName,winFeatures,winObj)
{
  var windowIsOpen = false;
  window.open(winURL,winName,winFeatures);
  windowIsOpen = true;  

  return windowIsOpen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well for taking the value of your variable you can return a boolean variable

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test for Window Already Open</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script>
function myOpenWindow(winURL,winName,winFeatures,winObj)
{
  var windowOpen = false;
  window.open(winURL,winName,winFeatures);
  windowOpen = true;  

  return windowOpen;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Click this link to open the new window:</h1>
<p><a href='javascript:;' onClick='javascript:gmyWin= return myOpenWindow("http://example:7001/tester/helloworld.jsp","myWin","height=630,width=1100",gmyWin);return false'>open new window</a> </p>
</body>
```

you have to add a return statement forthe boolean value